# Load part of bitmap in scrollable imageview and load the rest when scrolling?

Tags: android

I'm trying to load in part of a tall image into a scrollable imageview (imageview inside a scrollview).

It works with smaller images but if the images is bigger than 2048x2048 the app will crash due to open gl out of memory.

I can load part of the image with this:

```
private Bitmap decodeBitmapRegion(InputStream in, Rect region) {
    BitmapRegionDecoder decoder = null;
    try {
        decoder = BitmapRegionDecoder.newInstance(in, false);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    region.right = decoder.getWidth();
    Bitmap reg = decoder.decodeRegion(region, null);

    return reg;
}
```

Where the rectangle can be something like (0,0,DisplayWidth,800).

That works in most cases since i'm using the imageview to let the user crop a part of the image and save it as a coveriamge.The imageview has the same width as the display and the height of 400 dp.

So the image the user saves will be the same width as the orginal but only 400 dp's tall.

Is there anyway to make it possible for the user to scroll all the way to the bottom of the orginal image?

How does webview load images that are bigger than 2048x2048?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one thought.

Imagine your image broken into rows of bands.  Use a ListView to display the bands.  A ListView uses an adapter. In adapter.getView(), you use the decoder to load the appropriate band.

The ListView already does "recycling".  So, it more-or-less only holds enough rows to fill the screen.

This technique should work well if your images aren't too wide.  If they are, and it's not tall enough to occupy more than one screen height, you'll still have the same memory problems.  A more complicated solution would be to use some sort of grid view, but then you'll have to do your own view recycling.  Not too difficult, but harder than using ListView.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the functionality I wanted. But i don't think this is the best solution?
I loaded the image into a webview and then i took a screenshot of the visible part of the webview. After that i can save that bitmap and do whatever i want to it.

But there must be a better way to do this than to use a webview to show the original image?

Anyway here is what I did:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.jpg");
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imgView.setImageBitmap(getBitmapForVisibleRegion(webView));

        }
    });
}

public static Bitmap getBitmapForVisibleRegion(WebView webview) {
    Bitmap returnedBitmap = null;
    webview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(webview.getDrawingCache());
    webview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    return returnedBitmap;
}
```